# SQL - PROBLEMA setear distintas variables con un solo select de SQL

Tags: sql, variables, transact-sql

Necesito agregar en 4 variables, 4 datos buscados en un select. Les dejo el ejemplo de lo que estoy buscando

[**CODIGO**]

```
DECLARE @OT AS VARCHAR
DECLARE @COD_INSUMO AS VARCHAR
DECLARE @CANT_INS_OT AS DECIMAL(8,6)
DECLARE @SALDO AS DECIMAL(8,6)


SELECT (OT.t_comp + OT.n_of) AS 'OT'
     , INS.cod_insumo
     , INS.CANT_INS_OT
     , SAL.SALDO
  FROM CZAP10 OT 
        LEFT JOIN(SELECT INS.t_comp, INS.n_of, INS.cod_insumo, SUM(INS.cantidad) AS CANT_INS_OT
                    FROM CZAP21 INS
                GROUP BY INS.t_comp, INS.n_of, INS.cod_insumo
                ) INS ON OT.t_comp = INS.t_comp
                     AND OT.n_of = INS.n_of
        LEFT JOIN(SELECT SAL.cod_articu, SUM(SAL.cant_stock) AS SALDO
                    FROM CZSTA19 SAL
                GROUP BY SAL.cod_articu
                ) SAL ON INS.cod_insumo = SAL.cod_articu
 WHERE ESTADO = 'I'
```

[**FIN_CODIGO**]

En este caso donde debería poner los 'Set @OT = ...'

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si estas haciendo un Stored Procedure, donde necesitas leer los valores, entonces tenes que crearte un CURSOR para ir leyendo.

Ejemplo:

```
        DECLARE CurItems INSENSITIVE CURSOR FOR         
        SELECT (OT.t_comp + OT.n_of) AS 'OT'
             , INS.cod_insumo
             , INS.CANT_INS_OT
             , SAL.SALDO
          FROM CZAP10 OT 
                LEFT JOIN(SELECT INS.t_comp, INS.n_of, INS.cod_insumo, SUM(INS.cantidad) AS CANT_INS_OT
                            FROM CZAP21 INS
                        GROUP BY INS.t_comp, INS.n_of, INS.cod_insumo
                        ) INS ON OT.t_comp = INS.t_comp
                             AND OT.n_of = INS.n_of
                LEFT JOIN(SELECT SAL.cod_articu, SUM(SAL.cant_stock) AS SALDO
                            FROM CZSTA19 SAL
                        GROUP BY SAL.cod_articu
                        ) SAL ON INS.cod_insumo = SAL.cod_articu
         WHERE ESTADO = 'I'
        FOR READ ONLY 

        OPEN CurItems
        FETCH NEXT FROM CurItems INTO @OT, @COD_INSUMO, @CANT_INS_OT, @SALDO

        WHILE (@@fetch_status <> -1)
        BEGIN
        
            -- hacer lo que tengas que hacer
        
            -- sigo con el que sigue
            FETCH NEXT FROM CurItems INTO @OT, @COD_INSUMO, @CANT_INS_OT, @SALDO
        END
        CLOSE CurItems
        DEALLOCATE CurItems
```

Comment: Si esta es la solución que funcionó, es probable que se requiera una solución completamente distinta para evitar procesar fila por fila y aumentar la eficiencia.

Answer (score 4):

Tendría que ser algo así:

tienes que poner un TOP 1, porque si el query trae mas de un registro no te va a permitir setarlo.

```
DECLARE @OT AS VARCHAR
DECLARE @COD_INSUMO AS VARCHAR
DECLARE @CANT_INS_OT AS DECIMAL(8,6)
DECLARE @SALDO AS DECIMAL(8,6)


SELECT TOP 1

      @OT = (OT.t_comp + OT.n_of)
     ,@COD_INSUMO =  INS.cod_insumo
     ,@CANT_INS_OT =  INS.CANT_INS_OT
     ,@SALDO = SAL.SALDO
  FROM CZAP10 OT 
        LEFT JOIN(SELECT INS.t_comp, INS.n_of, INS.cod_insumo, SUM(INS.cantidad) AS CANT_INS_OT
                    FROM CZAP21 INS
                GROUP BY INS.t_comp, INS.n_of, INS.cod_insumo
                ) INS ON OT.t_comp = INS.t_comp
                     AND OT.n_of = INS.n_of
        LEFT JOIN(SELECT SAL.cod_articu, SUM(SAL.cant_stock) AS SALDO
                    FROM CZSTA19 SAL
                GROUP BY SAL.cod_articu
                ) SAL ON INS.cod_insumo = SAL.cod_articu
 WHERE ESTADO = 'I'
```

Answer (score 0):

Encontre está posible solución, agradecería si encuentran una solución más apropiada.

```
DROP TABLE #INSUMOS_RESERVADOS

SELECT (OT.t_comp + OT.n_of) AS 'OT'
     , INS.cod_insumo
     , INS.CANT_INS_OT
     , SAL.SALDO
INTO #INSUMOS_RESERVADOS
  FROM CZAP10 OT
        LEFT JOIN(SELECT INS.t_comp, INS.n_of, INS.cod_insumo, SUM(INS.cantidad) AS CANT_INS_OT
                    FROM CZAP21 INS
                GROUP BY INS.t_comp, INS.n_of, INS.cod_insumo
                ) INS ON OT.t_comp = INS.t_comp
                     AND OT.n_of = INS.n_of
        LEFT JOIN(SELECT SAL.cod_articu, SUM(SAL.cant_stock) AS SALDO
                    FROM CZSTA19 SAL
                GROUP BY SAL.cod_articu
                ) SAL ON INS.cod_insumo = SAL.cod_articu
 WHERE ESTADO = 'I'

DECLARE @OT AS VARCHAR
DECLARE @COD_INSUMO AS VARCHAR
DECLARE @CANT_INS_OT AS DECIMAL(8,6)
DECLARE @SALDO AS INT

SET @OT = (SELECT OT FROM #INSUMOS_RESERVADOS)
SET @COD_INSUMO = (SELECT cod_insumo FROM #INSUMOS_RESERVADOS)
SET @CANT_INS_OT = (SELECT CANT_INS_OT FROM #INSUMOS_RESERVADOS)
SET @SALDO = (SELECT SALDO FROM #INSUMOS_RESERVADOS)
```

Obviamente el 'Drop' lo va a ejecutar una vez creada la tabla

Comment: Para esto que estas haciendo es mejor la solución de @MrDonPh0x, que no necesita crear una tabla temporaria. Ojo que tenes que usar un `SELECT TOP 1` para que no te de eror si el SELECT te devuelve más de 1 valor